# lldb set maximum watchpoint count

Tags: debugging, lldb

I am facing a little problem with lldb, whenever I want to watch an expression, I get this error:

> error: Watchpoint creation failed (addr=0x61f2e70, size=4).
> error: number of supported hardware watchpoints (0) has been reached

And when I do

> watchpoint list -b

it tells me

> Number of supported hardware watchpoints: 0
>
> No watchpoints currently set.

Is there any command in lldb to set the maximum count of possible watchpoints / supported watchpoints?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The platform you're debugging does not support hardware breakpoints, or if it does, support was not configured into the version of lldb you're using.

Comment: Most of the current iOS and Mac hardware can handle 4 watchpoints.  What device/machine are you debugging on?  Watchpoint support is a somewhat new addition -- I can't remember exactly when it was added but if you're debugging an older iOS release (maybe iOS 5.x and older?), the hardware may support watchpoints but the debugserver in that release could not.  I don't remember the specifics of when this support was completed.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem on macOS with LLDB version "lldb-900.0.64" (part of Xcode 9.2). I believe that hardware watchpoints require superuser privileges: attaching to a running program would not let me set any watchpoints unless I ran the LLDB process with `sudo`. The process I was attaching to did not require `sudo`.